# 2 Brownian Motions with Non Zero Correlation and NOT jointly normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, brownian-motion, correlation

Is it possible for 2 Brownian Motions to have non-zero correlation without being jointly normal?

I'm a bit confused by the question.

I just assumed we always talk of multiple Brownian Motions as being jointly normally distributed with a certain covariance matrix etc.

I know in general two normal random variables have no reason a priori to be jointly normal. But does this also apply to Brownian motions which are a continuous stochastic process in which each B_i(t) is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance t for a given time t?

Comment: If $\{W_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a Weiner process and $X_t=W_t=Y_t$ then $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ and $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ are two Brownian motions with non zero correlation, but $(X_t,Y_t)$ is certainly not joint normal.

Comment: I see how this works. Since the correlation is clearly 1 and they are the same process so the joint density is degenerate (prob mass is on a line through the origin of slope 1 which has zero measure). But to be clear, there could also be non-trivial counterexamples too? Like if X_{t} and Y_{t} were both brownian motions with a certain non-zero correlation, their joint distribution does not 'have' to be normal? Perhaps they are correlated via a 3rd brownian motion process? I'm not sure how to explicitly construct such an example? But one certainly does exist?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following stochastic differential equation (SDE):

$dB_t = \rho(B_t, W_t)dW_t + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2(B_t, W_t)}dZ_t$, where $\{W_t\}_t$ and $\{Z_t\}_t$ are two independant Brownian motions, and $\rho$ is a function taking values in $[-1, 1]$. Then the solution $\{B_t\}_t$ of this SDE is a Brownian motion, as $d\langle B, B\rangle_t = \rho^2(B_t, W_t)dt + (1 - \rho^2(B_t, W_t))dt = dt$ and the joint law of $\{(B_t, W_t)\}_t$ has no reasons to be a Gaussian distribution.

You can have a look at the third chapter of Damien Bosc, *Three essays on modeling the dependence between financial assets*, PhD thesis, 2012.